# Best way StreamReader skipping Null or WhiteSpace line

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

After searching and trying the different ways I found I either wasn't happy with the way I was doing the code or it didn't work right for me. I'm new at programming so my understanding is limited. Please keep in mind with the answer.

I want to read a .csv file line by line and skipping lines that are blank. With the contents of the lines I want to put into a list of object. I have everything working except for the skipping line part. Also any feedback about improving any parts of my code are all welcome. I like constructive criticism.

```
public void CardaxCsvFileReader()
    {
        string cardaxCsvPath = (@"C:\Cardax2WkbTest\Cardax\CardaxTable.csv");

        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader cardaxSR =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(cardaxCsvPath)))
            {
                string line = "";
                string[] value = line.Split(',');

                while (!cardaxSR.EndOfStream)
                {                              // this commented out part is what I would like to work but doesn't seem to work.
                    line = cardaxSR.ReadLine();//.Skip(1).Where(item => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item));
                    value = line.Split(',');

                    if (line != ",,,,,") // using this as temp to skip the line because the above commented out part doesn't work.
                    {
                    CardaxDataObject cardaxCsvTest2 = new CardaxDataObject();

                    cardaxCsvTest2.EventID = Convert.ToInt32(value[0]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.FTItemID = Convert.ToInt32(value[1]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.PayrollNumber = Convert.ToInt32(value[2]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.EventDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value[3]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderFirstName = value[4];
                    cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderLastName = value[5];

                    Globals.CardaxQueryResult.Add(cardaxCsvTest2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            myLog.Error("Unable to open/read Cardax simulated punch csv file! " +
                "File already open or does not exist: \"{0}\"", cardaxCsvPath);
        }
```

Comment: `Split(",")` is an **awful** way to read csv data.

Comment: Indulge me with your thoughts about a better way. I'm open to trying to improve my code.

Comment: `Split(",")` is vulnerable to all kinds of edge cases (error prone) and it's not exactly fast. There are dedicated CSV parsers out there that are very easy to use, including at least two built into the .Net framework (a csv OLE database driver and the TextFieldParser class).

Comment: Also: when you talk about "blank" lines: will these lines still have 5 commas?

Comment: Yes the bank csv lines still have 5 ,commas. doing  this seemed to work...    <value = line.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

If you are lines are not truly blank and contain commas, you can split with [RemoveEmptyEntries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) option and then check the column count.

```
                while (!cardaxSR.EndOfStream)
                {                              // this commented out part is what I would like to work but doesn't seem to work.
                    line = cardaxSR.ReadLine();//.Skip(1).Where(item => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item));
                    value = line.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  // <-- Remove empty columns while splitting. It has a side-effect: Any record with just a single blank column will also get discarded by the if that follows.
                    if (value.length < 6)
                      continue;

                    CardaxDataObject cardaxCsvTest2 = new CardaxDataObject();

                    cardaxCsvTest2.EventID = Convert.ToInt32(value[0]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.FTItemID = Convert.ToInt32(value[1]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.PayrollNumber = Convert.ToInt32(value[2]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.EventDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value[3]);
                    cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderFirstName = value[4];
                    cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderLastName = value[5];

                    Globals.CardaxQueryResult.Add(cardaxCsvTest2);
                }
```

Another improvement feedback I have: When you catch an exception, it's a good practice to log the exception in addition to your custom error line. A custom error line might be good for say website users, but as a developer running some service you will appreciate the actual exception stack trace. It will help you debug a bug easier.

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myLog.Error("Unable to open/read Cardax simulated punch csv file! " +
            "File already open or does not exist: \"{0}\".\r\n Exception: {1}", cardaxCsvPath, ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I am curious if your lines are truly blank, or they have commas like ",,,,"? Can you post an input and output example where you see the problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I believe it doesn't think the lines are null or white space since it contains ,commas. It never triggers that if statement when it gets to the blank csv line. The contents of line contain ",,,,," for the blank line.

Comment: In the CSV file, all i did was insert a new line and never any information into that new line.

Comment: The updated version seem to work great. Also thanks for the feedback about adding to the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `value.Length == 6`, this way it'll skip lines which don't contain enough data for your columns

Comment: If I do that it throws the exception when it gets to the blank line. Also the bank line still as an array of 6 except it just reflects , commas instead of real information.

Comment: What exception? also, you can try using using `line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, this way you'll get an empty array on the ",,,,,"

Comment: My try catch exception. What I mean is when it tries to convert the "," comma to an Int32 and add it to my object list it crashes or throws the exception in my try catch which encases the whole method.

Comment: Commas get removed in the split method

Answer (score 0):

Use a **dedicated CSV parser**, such as the EasyCSV class available here<sup>*</sup>:

> https://github.com/jcoehoorn/EasyCSV

```
public void CardaxCsvFileReader()
{
    try 
    {
        string cardaxCsvPath = (@"C:\Cardax2WkbTest\Cardax\CardaxTable.csv");
        Globals.CardaxQueryResult =
           EasyCSV.FromFile(cardaxCsvPath)
              .Where(r => r.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)))
              .Select(r => CardaxDataObject() {
                    cardaxCsvTest2.EventID = int.Parse(r[0]),
                    cardaxCsvTest2.FTItemID = int.Parse(r[1]),
                    cardaxCsvTest2.PayrollNumber = int.Parse(r[2]),
                    cardaxCsvTest2.EventDateTime = DateTinme.Parse(r[3]),
                    cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderFirstName = r[4],
                    cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderLastName = r[5]
              }).ToList();      
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        myLog.Error("Unable to open/read Cardax simulated punch csv file! " +
            "File already open or does not exist: \"{0}\"", cardaxCsvPath);
    }
}
```

I also recommend re-thinking how you structure this. The code below is better practice:

```
public IEnumerable<CardaxDataObject> ReadCardaxCsvFile(string filename)
{
   //no try block at this level. Catch that in the method that calls this method

    return EasyCSV.FromFile(cardaxCsvPath)
          .Where(r => r.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)))
          // You may want to put a try/catch inside the `Select()` projection, though.
          // It would allow you continue if you fail to parse an individual record
          .Select(r => CardaxDataObject() {
                cardaxCsvTest2.EventID = int.Parse(r[0]),
                cardaxCsvTest2.FTItemID = int.Parse(r[1]),
                cardaxCsvTest2.PayrollNumber = int.Parse(r[2]),
                cardaxCsvTest2.EventDateTime = DateTinme.Parse(r[3]),
                cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderFirstName = r[4],
                cardaxCsvTest2.CardholderLastName = r[5]
         });      
}
```

Suddenly the method boils down to one statement (albeit a very long statement). Code like this is better, because it's *more powerful*, for three reasons: it's not limited to using just the one input file, it's not limited to only sending it's output to the one location, and it's not limited to only one way to handle errors. You'd call it like this:

```
try 
{
    string cardaxCsvPath = (@"C:\Cardax2WkbTest\Cardax\CardaxTable.csv");
    Globals.CardaxQueryResult = ReadCardaxCsvFile(cardaxCsvPath).ToList();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    myLog.Error("Unable to open/read Cardax simulated punch csv file! " +
            "File already open or does not exist: \"{0}\"", cardaxCsvPath);
}
```

or like this:

```
try 
{
    string cardaxCsvPath = (@"C:\Cardax2WkbTest\Cardax\CardaxTable.csv");
    foreach (var result in ReadCardaxCsvFile(cardaxCsvPath))
    {
        Globals.CardaxQueryResult.Add(result);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    myLog.Error("Unable to open/read Cardax simulated punch csv file! " +
            "File already open or does not exist: \"{0}\"", cardaxCsvPath);
}
```

I also recommend against using a `Globals`class like this. Find a more meaningful object with which you can associate this data.

---

<sup><sup>* Disclaimer: I am the author of that parser</sup></sup>

Comment: When I have some extra time I will look into this. Thank you.